# Cannot read property '0' of undefined when looping through JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm retrieving some information in JSON using the jQuery method and am getting the following error.

In addition I want to create a simple chart with uses of **Chart.js** that presents my json files.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

**JavaScript**

```
$.getJSON("geodata/passengerSub1_2.json", function(data) {
    var labels = data.customers[0].amounts.map(function(e) {
       return e[0];
    });    
    var data = data.customers[0].amounts.map(function(e) {
       return e[1];
    });
    var barChartSub1 = document.getElementById('barChart1').getContext('2d');

    var chart = new Chart(barChartSub1, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
           labels: labels,
           datasets: [{
              backgroundColor: 'rgb(129, 198, 2228)',
              borderColor: 'rgb(0, 150, 215)',
              data: data
           }]
        },
        options: {
           responsive: 'true',
        }
     });
  });
```

**JSON**

```
{
  "customers": [
    {
      "first_name": "John",
      "last_name": "Doe",
      "account": "123456",
      "period": "13th July - 13th August",
      "due_date": "14th September",
      "amounts": [
        ["January 2017", 121.23],
        ["February 2017", 145.23],
        ["March 2017", 55.12],
        ["April 2017", 78.58],
        ["May 2017", 89.13],
        ["June 2017", 45.78],
        ["July 2017", 90.22]
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: it's undefined, so `JSON` failed to fetch, check `console.log(data)`

Comment: Are you sure that you are able to read the json file? I think, getJson() failed

Comment: Everything works just fine, your error is **you redefined the data variable**, so use some other variable name (I used `chartData`) for the chart's data. Check [this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ur2cL8gy/), than you can delete the question...

Comment: Thanks.The problem is the json file  is stored locally and I dont want to put it into my webapp @FlashThunder

Comment: There is no way to read it without user interaction, you would need to put some input and select the path manually every time

Comment: Even with local web server?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't matter. It's for security reasons, so any website (even the local one) wouldn't have access to your hard drives.

Comment: Perhaps I can arrange something on cloud basis (Drive etc.). Can you recommend something? Due when I load everything into my web app it slows down performance

Comment: Thanks. I found one myjson API seems quite useful :)